# Update delegate everytime some function run

Tags: c#, delegates

OK. I think me title is very bad. I don't know that much of delegates, only that they are like function pointers in C...
I have some code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
namespace lol
{
    class FetchHttpSite
    {
        public static string Download(string url, string ip)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            req.UserAgent = UserAgent.Random();
            req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount) {
                return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 0);
            };

            HttpWebResponse webResponse;

            string content;

            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                content = stream.ReadToEnd();

            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to fetch sites with different IPs. But when I tried this i realized that this delegate is like... static xD. It just takes the first IP I give him. So if I feed him a new IP he will still use the first he got. I found that BindIPEndPointDelegate code thingy here on Stackoverflow btw.

So what I want that delegate to always take that string ip. Like, update itself all the time. Is this possible. How do I do this? Is it possible? Could I do this another way?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I want to fetch the site using that IP I feed the method. So when the webserver get my request my address is string ip argument. :)

The method works! You see I've tried before: return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 0);, e.g. Console.Writeline("hello!");, then it will just run once! Even thou I ask 100x. It only takes the IP from the first one to use the method. Thank you!

EDIT 2:

Pasted the whole code.

Comment: The delegate uses the `ip` parameter that you pass into the `Download` method. Which IP do you want it to use instead?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the function?  It is tough to tell, but I suspect this has to do with a concept called closures.